# VS Code Extension: Remote - SSH. How do I specify a ssh command for connection

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I have a server to which the connection SSH is as follows:

```
ssh -t admin@192.168.1.10 /bin/bash
```

If I don't specify `/bin/bash` explicitly, it runs another application instead of the shell (don't have access in the server to change this).

How do I configure the `/bin/bash shell` command in Remote-SSH extension? The current configuration is:

```
Host 192.168.1.10
  HostName 192.168.1.10
  User admin
  RequestTTY yes
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RemoteCommand`

```
Host 192.168.1.10
  HostName 192.168.1.10
  User admin
  RequestTTY yes
  RemoteCommand /bin/bash
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work in my case. Running `ssh` from command line works, but not from Visual Studio Code.  On VS Code output window, it shows the text from the screen I'm trying to avoid with using `/bin/bash`.

Comment: In my test, VSCode is using RemoteCommand defined in ssh configuration.

Comment: It cant't work with VSCode, see why at [microsoft: Can't connect with RemoteCommand in ssh config #481](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/481)

Comment: Still not working, looks like the latest bug / feature request related to this is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4474